# Starting Jetty before test phase in a Maven multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, jetty, overlays

I have a WAR Module in a multi-module Maven project (let's say foo-web), which realises a web-service. Then I have a foo-cli, which implements a web service client and tests it in a couple of unit tests.

In order to make this working, I start Jetty before the test phase this way:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-web</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <type>war</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>         
...
<plugin>
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>8.1.5.v20120716</version>
   <configuration>

     <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
     <useTestScope>true</useTestScope>
     <connectors>
       <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
         <port>8080</port>
         <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
       </connector>
     </connectors>
   </configuration>

<executions>
    <execution>
      <id>start-jetty</id>
      <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <daemon>true</daemon>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
   </executions>          
</plugin>
```

This works perfectly well while I run 'mvn test' from within the foo-cli module (it even stops automatically, with no need to specify anything else). However, when I attempt to go to the upper level (foo) and issue 'mvn test' from there, i.e., I try to run all the tests for all the modules in the project, it fails with '404 - not found'. From the output, I can see that the overlay (the war dependency) seems to be totally ignored.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try moving your integration test to the top level project. This way it will run after the WAR artifact has been built.

Have you had a look at the [Maven Failsafe Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/)? It's designed for the sort of thing you're doing, which is actually an integration test and not a unit test. The page offers some good advice on why you might want to use the `integration-test` phase for your integration testing.

Namely, it describes why you might want to do `start-jetty` during `pre-integration-test` and so on, so that you can tear it all down appropriately.

Comment: Thank Jonathan. I've seen Failsafe, but I believe I'm unit-testing the web service client here, not doing an integration test, so I'd like to make it working as such.

Moreover, If I have to move to Failsafe, how would the code that invokes the web service via the client look like? At the moment it is a JUnit-annotated class.

Comment: If you move to failsafe, your config would be similar. You'd do a `start-jetty` task in the `pre-integration-test` phase instead of `process-test-classes`. Then do failsafe, then `stop-jetty` in `post-integration-test`, and finally do a `verify` task.

Comment: Yes, but what about the Java class that realises the Junit test? This is the one that invokes the web service. If it's annotated with JUnit (i.e., @Test), how does Maven understand that this is an integration test and not a unit test? I understand that in case surefire attempted to run it, it would not find the web server running, cause this is started later. What am I missing?

Comment: Ahh I see. There's nothing 'special' about unit and integration tests as far as JUnit is concerned. Failsafe runs the tests using Surefire, so you'd still do `@Test` annotations. You can separate out integration tests from unit tests by putting them in another directory like `/src/integration/java` or use JUnit 4.8 groups.

Comment: OK, it seems that such distinction is made by naming the Integration Test classes like SomeClassIT (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/testng.html). To me this is twisted and confusing, but I'm glad I've learnt something more. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @zakmck In your case you are running integration tests.